# How to join two tables from different databases

Tags: php, mysql

How to join two tables from different databases.  One database is localhost, the other is in online.

```
$connectA = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','abc');
$connectB = mysql_connect('xxx','yyy','zzz','xyz');
```

I want to join **department_name** from table **department** which is having database **abc** and **xyz**.

Comment: You'll need to do the processing in PHP. As the databases are not on the same server, straight `JOIN`s are not possible. Also, move away from the `mysql_` function set as it has been deprecated - look into `PDO` or `mysqli`. I assume that the `abc` and `xyz` parameters are being used to create a new link rather than re-use a previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot as long as by `join` you mean using `SQL JOINS`. It is, because SQL query is always sent to specific database or server.

You need to send two independent queries, one for each database and then provide some logic in PHP to join them either by `array_merge` (full join) or some more advanced scripting.

Can't help more without seeing some code of your own.

Comment: can u explain me with an example .

Answer (score 0):

If the MySQL user has access to both databases and they are on the same host (i.e. both DBs are accessible from the same connection) you could:

- Keep one connection open and call `mysql_select_db()` to swap between as necessary. I am not sure this is a clean solution and you could end up querying the wrong database.
- Specify the database name when you reference tables within your queries (e.g. `SELECT * FROM database2.tablename`). This is likely to be a pain to implement.

Also please read troelskn's answer because that is a better approach if you are able to use PDO rather than the older extensions.

Comment: OP said that one is localhost and other one is online (I assume he works with php on his machine and uses one database from his machine and one from the internet)

Answer (score 0):

As already has been said, it is not possible.
I would save the database connections and switch between the databases.

Just a simple example (and with mysqli)

```
$db1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$db2 = mysqli_connect("localhost2", "my_user2", "my_password2", "world2");
```

And then when you want to execute a query

```
mysqli_query($db1, "SELECT * ...");
```

or other database

```
mysqli_query($db2, "SELECT * ...");
```

Save the results from your query's in arrays and then use for example `array_merge` to join them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Use can use database federation (data virtualization) technologies like Teiid http://teiid.io and join the tables across the databases or even data from files and web services.