# Select two or multiple tables from different databases not working on linux cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This query is working on local xampp:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.telephone
FROM db1.table1 t1
INNER JOIN db2.table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

But the same query isn't working on LINUX cPanel

```
<?php 

    $hostname='localhost'; 
    $username='root'; 
    $password=''; 
    $db='smart_software'; 

    $username2='root'; 
    $password2=''; 
    $db2='smart_stationary'; 

    $con1 = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db); 
    $con2 = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username2, $password2, $db2);

    $result=mysqli_query($con2,"select MSC.mobile_sub_cat_id, MSC.employee_id, ED.employee_name, LN.location, MC.mobile_cat_name, MSC.service_provider, MSC.number FROM smart_stationary.mobile_sub_cat MSC LEFT JOIN smart_stationary.mobile_cat MC ON MC.mobile_cat_id=MSC.mobile_cat_id LEFT JOIN smart_software.employee_details ED ON ED.employee_id=MSC.employee_id LEFT JOIN smart_stationary.location LN ON LN.location_id=MSC.location_id"); 

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo $row['location']; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: what's the question here? what problem you are facing? what is expected?

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT 
t1.id, 
t1.name, 
t2.id, 
t2.telephone
FROM db1.table1 t1

LEFT JOIN db2.table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;");
     
     
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: same conditions is working fine with local xampp, but same condition is not working linux cpanel

Comment: did you get any error on `linux cpanel` when you tried your code.?Very less info to help you.

Comment: no error shows. but result not showing.

Comment: Please add your full php code. it's very less code to do any comments or modification

Comment: My guess is your user does not have permission to access both databases.  You'll get a table or database does not exist error (not a user validation error) confusingly.  This would especially be the case if they (the databases) belong to two different C-Panel users.  Whenever code works in Development and not Production, Check the environmental specific stuff.  Permission being one of the first among those.

Comment: both databases are in same cpanel only

Answer (score 0):

---

-Are u sure both database in mysql access

1. create user on cpanel phpmyadmin.
2. set privilege

Comment: Yes created and set privilege

Comment: also use mysql_select_db().

Comment: $con1 = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db); 
    $con2 = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username2, $password2, $db2);

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO username@host;

Comment: use array_merge() for both connection

Comment: $newcon = array_merge($con1,$con2)

Comment: for your refrence link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694420/how-to-join-two-tables-from-different-databases

Comment: how we can GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to @DBNAME

Comment: please read prev message  array_merge() or follow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694420/how-to-join-two-tables-from-different-databases